# Should the redux store keep only non-UI states?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a catalog store (redux) with categories and products. Based on the UI events (for example 'filtered' or a 'category' that has been collapsed), the UI state will change - a new state is derived from the catalog store.

In the redux ToDo example, the [visibility filter](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/reducers/visibilityFilter.js) is managed as part of the redux store. The filter is a UI state, and shouldn't that be managed part of the component states? So in my example, all the UI states handled in the components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping both "application" state and "UI" state in a Redux store is entirely reasonable.  Ultimately, it's up to you what data you put in your store.  See [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state)  for further discussion on this topic.

Comment: I know this is an old question but would you recommend separate stores for the application and UI state? Why/why not?

Comment: No, I wouldn't.  At a minimum, React-Redux assumes you only have a single store, and `<Provider>` makes that one store accessible to the entire React component tree.  It's also not an idiomatic Redux pattern at all.